# Cannot load local JSON file in django

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am building a web app in Django. I am a newbie and still learning. I need some help with the dev.

In the final app the JSON will be returned via a web service but it is not ready yet. So, for the sake of dev, I have created a sample JSON file (.json). Here is what it looks like: http://pastebin.com/A91q557K

Now I checked if the JSON is being read or not. Here is the code:

```
from pprint import pprint
json_data=open('config.json')

data = json.load(json_data)
pprint(data)
json_data.close()
```

But, it gives an error saying "No JSON object could be decoded". I tried searching around in the forum. People said it meant that it is not getting the JSON content.

I am not sure why it cannot decode the JSON. The open() seems to go through fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: looks like a `,` is missing in all of your dictionary elements. I have copied the first dictionary element in your list and here, you can see that a comma is missing between the keys "lastname" and "employeenumber". `{        "firstName" : "Jamie","lastName" : "Lambier" "employeeNumber" :239657}` .

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have put the commas but the error persists.

Comment: I have placed the commas in all the dictionaries, and then I tried to evaluate whether it is in proper json format or not by pasting that string in (http://json.parser.online.fr/) . And looks like the data you have written in your `config.json` is not in valid json format. Can you tell me how what steps you have taken to create the `config.json` file

Comment: I validated the json at jsonlint.com and it says it is fine.

Comment: Is the code still not working with the latest json ? P.S: I have gone through your latest "json string" link and yeah now it is in valid format

Answer (score 0):

This is working with your file:

```
In [1]: import json

In [2]: with open('config.json') as json_data:
...:     data = json.load(json_data)
...:     print data
...:    
[{u'lastName': u'Chepesky', u'employeeNumber': u'01840192', u'firstName': u'Mike'}, {u'lastName': u'Barichak', u'employeeNumber': u'47901927', u'firstName': u'Westlee'}, {u'lastName': u'Lambier', u'employeeNumber': u'51239657', u'firstName': u'Jamie'}, {u'lastName': u'Marshall', u'employeeNumber': u'41239520', u'firstName': u'Denise'}, {u'lastName': u'Taylor', u'employeeNumber': u'01963597', u'firstName': u'Matthew'}, {u'lastName': u'Tiegs', u'employeeNumber': u'65321951', u'firstName': u'Mark'}, {u'lastName': u'Tetzel', u'employeeNumber': u'03266987', u'firstName': u'Karla'}, {u'lastName': u'Dundas', u'employeeNumber': u'29472012', u'firstName': u'Ian'}, {u'lastName': u'Cacciacarro', u'employeeNumber': u'56446691', u'firstName': u'Marco'}]
```

Comment: i'd fetched your file, and try mine code with it, and it's working i have no idea where is your problem